# Java DigestUtils doesn't calculate SHA-256 correcly?

Tags: java, file, sha256

I have a file called `test.sha256`, which contains:

```
5891b5b522d5df086d0ff0b110fbd9d21bb4fc7163af34d08286a2e846f6be03
```

I have another file called `data.txt`, which contains:

```
hello
```

I know that when using `Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(data.txt));` the result is an array of `signed` bytes. However what if I should do following:

1. Read `test.sha256`, which contains sha256 hash of `data.txt`
2. Read `data.txt` and create sha256 hash from that file
3. Compare (1) and (2)

Problem is that when I use:

```
DigestUtils.getDigest("SHA-256").digest(Files.readAllBytes(data.txt))
```

Result differs from the content of `test.sha256` file. And that is because Java cannot iterpret `unsigned` bytes using `Files.readAllBytes`, but can do that using `DigestUtils.getDigest().digest`.

Note though, that "SHA-256" is configurable, i.e I don't hardcode it in real code (it is passed as an argument to the method).

My question is how I can compare hash "A" that has been red from a file and the hash that is generated from a data of file "B" ? Where "A" is the actual hash of "B".

UPD: I confirm that they differ:

```
Arrays.equals(DigestUtils.sha256(Files.readAllBytes(data.txt)), Files.readAllBytes(test.sha256));
```

Java class being used: `import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils`

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java using signed bytes instead of unsigned bytes... That said, please specify what this `DigestUtils` class is. The problems is that a digest returns bytes, while your test.sha256 contains hex encoded bytes. You either need to encode the output of `digest` as hex or decode the contents of test.sha256 from hex to bytes (e.g. using Java 17 and higher `HexFormat`)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the quick response, that class `import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils`

Comment: Or use `DigestUtils.sha256Hex(...)`.

Comment: That said, a text file that only has content `hello` (no whitespace or unprintable characters), does not have a SHA-256 of "5891b5b522d5df086d0ff0b110fbd9d21bb4fc7163af34d08286a2e846f6be03", the correct hash would be "2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824"

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that's  not correct, use `sha256sum data.txt` on Linux and will get the same I did

Comment: Never mind, the hash you have occurs when the file contains `hello\n` (where \n represent a linefeed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that the output of `DigestUtils.getDigest("SHA-256").digest(..)` is a byte array of the raw bytes of the digest, while your `test.sha256` file contains a hex encoded value.

To address this problem, you'll need to encode the raw bytes to hex, for example using `HexFormat` (introduced in Java 17), or the `DigestUtil.sha256Hex(..)` method which will perform the digest and then produce a hex-encoded string.

For example:

```
System.out.println(DigestUtils.sha256Hex(Files.readAllBytes(data)));
```

and

```
Objects.equals(
        DigestUtils.sha256Hex(Files.readAllBytes(data)),
        Files.readString(test.sha256));
```

Or, if you want to keep the hash parameterized and you cannot use `HexFormat` of Java 17:

```
Hex.encodeHexString(
        DigestUtils.getDigest("SHA-256")
                .digest(Files.readAllBytes(data)));
```

where `Hex` is `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex`.

Comment: yeah `sha256hex` is a solution, however I have "SHA-x" value configurable, i.e passed as an argument to the function. But seems like I don't have any other solutions. Damn Java :(

Java 17 cannot be used, since older code snippets dont compile so

Comment: @ojacomarket You can use `Hex.encodeHexString(...)`, where `Hex` is `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex`.

Comment: adding `.getBytes()` behind the `Hex.encodeHexString` does what I want, thank you, accepting!

Comment: @ojacomarket Why not just compare string outputs? E.g. using `Files.readString(..)` on the test.sha256 file to compare against the `Hex.encodeHexString` output.

Comment: Some tools use 0-9a-f for hex and some use 0-9A-F, so in general to compare hex you usually want `String.equalsIgnoreCase` or similar (which Java has back to 1, FWIW)